# How to transform a matrix $A$ so that $\operatorname{norm}(A \times B) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two matrices, $A$ and $B$. I would like to find the transform $f$ makes the minimum change to $A$ to satisfy the constraint $\operatorname{norm}(f(A) \times B) = 0$, where norm is the $L_1$ norm.

In other words, I want to find $f$ so that $f(A) \times B$ is a matrix with all zeros.

The trivial solution would be to set all of the elements of $A$ to zero, but that is not an acceptable solution in this case.

I apologize in advance if the notation is not clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say "minimum change", does that mean that you want to minimize the norm $\|A - f(A)\|$? Does it matter which norm we minimize this with respect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you mean by a "minimum" change, so for my own convenience I'll assume that you want to minimize $\|A - f(A)\|_F$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).

Note that a matrix $M$ will satisfy $MB = 0$ if and only if each row $r$ of $M$ satisfies $rB = 0$. [In fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors), for any row-vector $r$, the nearest vector for which $rB = 0$ is given by $r(I - BB^+)$, where $B^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

So, we should take $f(A)$ to be the matrix obtained by replacing each row $r$ with $r(I - BB^+)$. That is,
$$
f(A) = A(I - BB^+).
$$

Comment: Thank you! "minimum" was intentionally left as open to interpretation.